# Changing background image with timer

Tags: vb.net, image-processing, timer

Here is my code in vb.net for automatically changing image using timer but code doesn't work...

```
 Private Sub Timer1_Tick(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
    Me.BackgroundImage = Image.FromFile("C:\images\\" + Label1.Text + "1.jpg")
    Dim i As Integer = Convert.ToInt32(Label1.Text)
    i += 1

    If (i > 4) Then
        i = 1
    End If
    Label1.Text = i.ToString()
 End Sub
```

Comment: Your code looks reasonable.  Do you get an error message?  Are you sure the filename is correct?

Comment: define "doesnt work"  I cant see the screen from here.  If the timer's interval is too short it could be changing but you cant tell because it happens so fast.  You could try it from a button click to tell if it works and debug the arts that do not before you post to a timer.

Comment: Look at the string for the path.  It contains \\, and I think it should be \.  Also, is the file name 11.jpg, then 21.jpg, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Move the counter out to class level.  Incorporating the comments from dbasnett as well.  Also, shouldn't the label reflect the current image number?  The way you have it the value in the Label is one "ahead" of the background image.

Try something more like:

```
Private i As Integer = 1

Private Sub Timer1_Tick(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
    Dim FileName As String = "C:\images\" & i.ToString & ".jpg"
    Try
        Me.BackgroundImage = Image.FromFile(FileName)
        Label1.Text = i.ToString()

        i += 1
        If (i > 4) Then
            i = 1
        End If
    Catch ex As Exception
        Debug.Print(FileName)
        MessageBox.Show(FileName & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & ex.ToString, "Error Loading Image")
    End Try
End Sub
```

Comment: no sir it cant work. i just got error is "FILE NOT FOUND EXCEPTION Was UNHANDLED "

Comment: Well...it's pretty evident that the file is either not there, or you are constructing the name wrong.  Try using Debug.Print() to output the filename to help you troubleshoot.

Comment: file is already in correct location. bt why it does not work.

Comment: FILE NOT FOUND means the file isn't there.  You need to troubleshoot and look very closely at the file name versus the location...check the edited code above.